# Import Data from MS Access 2003 to excel with VB Adodb connection

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am very new in VB and try to learn something.Actully i just want to import from date and to date data from MS Access 2003 table to Excel 2003 using VB Adodb Recordset.Your cooperation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you need all the records, you can simply select the columns then copy and paste in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Typical code for this would be:

```
Set db = Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(DBName, False, False, DBpwd)
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT fromdate, todate FROM yourtable;")
sheets("sheet 1").range("A1").copyFromRecordset rs1


rs1.Close
db.close
Set rs1 = Nothing
St db = Nothing
```

Make sure tools -> references are set in your vba editor to include 'Microsoft DAO x.xx library'